# Large image in UIWebView should scale to full size when displaying the view controller

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, zooming, scale

I want to display a large image on a `UIWebView` so that the user sees the full image when he comes to this screen. The webview should take such a scale that it takes the whole width of the image and adapts it according to the available screen width (the ratio width/height of the image should stay the same). So the webview has to zoom out.

Therefore I used the `scalesPageToFit` property. The image is about 3900x2613, but you can use [another large image](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/16million-pschmidt.png) too. What is also interesting is that the user can't fully zoom out manually to see the whole image.

Now I made a test project and tried different solutions to load the image (locally, web ressource, NSData, ...). Now I provide you some example code in C#.

Locally:

```
webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
View.AddSubview (webView);
string filePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("sample", "jpg");
NSUrl fileURL = new NSUrl (filePath);
webView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (fileURL));
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

Or from web ressource:

```
webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
View.AddSubview (webView);
webView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl("http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/16million-pschmidt.png")));
```

Or with local image and HTML:

```
webView = new UIWebView ();
webView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
View.AddSubview (webView);
NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary ();
viewsDictionary ["webView"] = webView;

View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[webView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[webView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
NSUrl baseUrl = new NSUrl (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, true);
string fileName = "some.jpg";
string localDocUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
string webViewContent = String.Format ("<html><body><img src=\"{0}\" width=\"100%\"/></body></html>", localDocUrl);
webView.LoadHtmlString (webViewContent, baseUrl);
```

You can of course provide code examples in Objective-C/Swift for your answers! In my real project I'm working with NSData, where I get a string from a webservice. I also tried some solutions of different similar posts on SO, but the scaling stayed wrong.

If you enter the URL into Safari the webview seems to do everything right. But why not in my code?

Comment: Why don't you use UIScrollView? You could pinch zoom and swipe scroll in the image. Just use zoomToRect to show the whole image. [Basic Zooming Using the Pinch Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html)

Comment: Because I'm also presenting more than images and the webview worked nice so far. It would be nice if I could keep the webview. Thanks for your addition.

Comment: Have you tried to make an HTML and reference the image from there? You could scale it with css to fill the whole screen. To load local images from the assets, set the base url to NSBundle.mainBundle.bundlePath. Also, adding the following at the beginning of the HTML might help: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">`.

Comment: I tried using HTML. When I use your meta tag then the image is shown in full size but I want to see the whole image as it would be zoomed out. This is the code I used `<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"></head><body><img src="some.jpg" /></body></html>`. With `width="100%"` the user cannot zoom as much as it would be possible (see my edited questin how I've done it for now). The other problem with the HTML approach is the following: I have the data stored into `NSData`. I'd need to store it locally and then display it.

Comment: Is there a better approach? Also what I don't get is, that using `scalesPageToFit` does work most of the time except for the large image. Why does the large image doesn't work here? I'm sure that I'm not the only one who has this problem.

Comment: Better approach is to use ScrollView. I don't think WebView is a very reliable way to do this. How are you presenting more than images in the WebView if the image is full screen and takes all screen space?

Comment: The webview can also present a pdf, docx and so on. When you open such a document you see the whole page at once (as it should do with the image). The user has the option to zoom in if he wants. All this is done by simply setting `scalesPageToFit` to *YES*. If you open the linked image in my question Safari is doing it automatically right. But why not in the `UIWebView`?

Comment: Since you are using `UIWebView` for loading image (I don't know why you wouldn't use UIImageView and an asynchronous request), why not to make a small HTML snippet that does 100% with? That way the zoom out will work for sure (it will be just any other website that has the functionality)

Comment: @Gasim: I don't use `UIImageView` because I also use other filetypes too. Also I don't have the data saved onto disk, but I think I'll have to. I tried it with HTML as you can see in my third code example. One thing which doesn't work here is if you rotate the device. Shouldn't the image adapt to the change in screen size?

Comment: It should. Just put the CSS of `img` tag to `width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:100%`. Besides that, if I were you I would have made two views, UIImageView for images, UIWebView for other stuff.

Comment: And forgot to mention. Viewport is important on mobile devices.

Comment: @Gasim: If I use something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` then I can't fully zoom into the image. I'll try your approach.

Comment: @Gasim: Now I tried your *style* attribute and only on first orientation change it adapts correctly. Try the following: 1. Load image onto `UIWebView` 2. Go from portrait into landscape 3. Zoom in and then out to see the complete image 4. Go to portrait. In the last step you should see the whole image imho, but it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean fully zoom in? I thought you wanted to fully zoom out?

Comment: I'll check it in a bit and let you know

Comment: @Gasim: The image is a big image. If you open the view you should see the whole image at once. The user should be able to zoom in and out as he wants and on orientation change the view should be adapted accordingly. Safari is handling all that very well but with my `UIWebView` I wasn't able to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you able to solve issue ?. If you could help me then .For Large Image   I  have same issue ,If I used HTML then user not able to zoom much in ,If i use URLRequest then image is by default zoomed pls see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151187/uiwebview-zooming-pdf-and-large-images-zoom-by-defaults-ios

Comment: @MikeAlter: You first have to store the file on disk (not RAM). Then you could use `UIImageView` to show the image and implement the gesture recognizer yourself and scale the image accordingly. I never implemented this. Also there are some guides by Apple like for example [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html), which shows a solution to handle large image files (in memory). But I'm afraid that this might not be the solution you are seeking for, because it doesn't treat your zooming issue ...

Comment: @testing Thanks for replay ,I am already working with downloaded images ,  As I am using UIWebview to show PDF and Image both , so I am seraching solution for UIWebview Only. With HTML I can show user full image but user not able to zoom much deeper (how to do it ? If you know) .

Comment: @MikeAlter: I used `webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;` and `webView.LoadData (documentData, "image/jpeg", "", baseUrl);`, but I think there is still the zooming issue in it (I never touched this anymore). Perhaps you can scale down the image (as quick hack)?