# UIWebview Zooming PDF and Large . Images Zoom By defaults IOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am  using `UIWebView` to load PDF and images with zooming functionality . 
For that I checked `webView.scalesPageToFit` Property to true and it is working fine .

But my issue is

When I load large Images (2496 * 3507) it shows by default Zoomed that I don't want I want size to fit

To overcome this issue

I implemented Web view delegate with following code

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let zoom = webView.bounds.size.width / webView.scrollView.contentSize.width
    webView .stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.style.zoom = \(zoom);")

}
```

Now the issue of Default zoom is resolved but webview allows to scroll to vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You can stop scrollView to scroll Vertically and Horizontally using below code. You can also stop bounces.

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks , But It can not be a solution to disable scroll, as i am also showing PDF then it will not scroll to next  page of pdf , I want Size to FIT for images . with my code i am able to achieve it but Scrolling (Content size) is not fitting (More than Image), If you could help me for this scenario